# Unity 3D Android and File

Tags: android, file, mobile, unity-game-engine, apk

I have a problem with Android and Unity 3D. I have a file read code. When I put my code on the computer, it works. However, my code does not work on Android (Mobile). How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

```
FileInfo theSourceFile = new FileInfo(filename);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fname))
    {
        StreamReader reader = theSourceFile.OpenText();
        string text = reader.ReadLine();
        print(string);
    }
```

**EDIT** updated code

```
string filename = "file.txt";
FileInfo theSourceFile = new FileInfo(filename);
filename = Application.persistentDataPath + "/"+filename;
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename,"Test");
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
    {
        StreamReader reader = theSourceFile.OpenText();
        string text = reader.ReadLine();
        print(string);
    }
```

Comment: Where is `filename` defined? What does it look like? Post how the url is

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your build settings for android Device.
Change Configuration >> write access to external (sd card).

if not, your app is pointing to internal path and you need root permission in your android device.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `Application.persistentDataPath` on Android to be able to read anything.

Change that to `string filename = Application.persistentDataPath + "/file.txt";` and your code should work fine.

Bear in mind that before the read function can work, you must write to the directory first. So `file.txt` must exist in `Application.persistentDataPath` first.

For example

```
string filename = Application.persistentDataPath + "/file.txt";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename,"Test");
```

EDIT:

You new code is still not working because you had `FileInfo theSourceFile = new FileInfo(filename);` before `filename = Application.persistentDataPath + "/"+filename;`. This means that the file name is still **not** valid. Pay attention the **order** your script **execute**. After switching it, it worked on my Android. Below is the whole code.

```
string filename = "file.txt";
filename = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename;
System.IO.FileInfo theSourceFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(filename);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, "Test");
if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
{
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = theSourceFile.OpenText();
    string text = reader.ReadLine();
    print(text);
}
```

Comment: I got "file does not exist" message.

Comment: @Leo You must write to that file before you can use it. Look at my edit. Use File.write and make sure to use the right url in my answer. You can then read it with File.Read....

Comment: I did it but, still does not work on my mobile phone.

Comment: @Leo Put **Edit** in your question and post your new/current code that is not working. Edit and add it to your question. Don't delete your old post.

Comment: @Leo Even after your edit, there was still a problem because of the order you put the code. I copied your new code and corrected it. It should work now. Look at working code, under Edit in my answer.

Comment: I wrote edited code but, Unity 3D sent to me error message. FormatException: Unknown char: T
System.Double.Parse (System.String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Double.cs:209)
System.Single.Parse (System.String s) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Single.cs:183)
Read2.ReadFile (System.String fname) (at Assets/Read2.cs:58)

Comment: @Leo Copy the code from my Edited answer not from the Edited question I made. Copy it directly from my answer directly and paste it into the editor. This is the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/37317866/3785314 It works without error. Remove any other code in your script to verify this.

Comment: @Leo Please read carefully. Disable other scripts in your project. Remove other codes in your scripts and run just this code in this answer. Your problem is solved. You are having another problem right now because you did `float.Parse(string s)` somewhere in your code. That is not related to this problem. You can also verify this by creating a new Project and trying this code only.It should work.

Comment: Okay. I will try. Thank you for helping me.